# What does the function free() do in PHP?

Tags: php

In the *first* code example on [this page](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php), this is the *second last* function called.

The comment says it frees the result set, but I am not able to understand what exactly is meant by freeing a result set? The result set is an Object so what is meant by freeing it?

```
/* free result set */
$result->free();
```

Comment: your question says "this page"? which page? there is no link.

Comment: @Gordon http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php Sorry

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The creation of a result set is a form of dynamic memory allocation, almost certainly done when an SQL query was executed, something like:

```
$conn = some_connection_to_database();
$rows = $conn->query("select name from etc_passwd where group = 'admin'")
```

Since the intent is for you to then *use* that result set, it cannot be freed as part of the query itself.

So, once the query is run and the result set is returned, *you* are responsible for freeing that memory when you're done with it.

That is where `free()` will be used. The basic idea (in English) is:

- Get result set from somewhere.
- Use it.
- Return it to its source (this is the `free` bit).